# split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.4

In python2 i could go from this pandas series

```
        0
0    [a,b,c]
```

with s.str.split(',',expand=True) into this:

```
  0 1 2

0 a b c
```

and now (ipython3) i cant, because lack of "expand" argument. How I can do it in other way?

Comment: This is a pandas version issue rather than Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your environment's pandas version.  According to the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), expand was recently added so it looks like you regressed your version somehow.

> expand : bool, default False If True, return DataFrame/MultiIndex
>   expanding dimensionality. If False, return Series/Index. New in
>   version 0.16.1.

Based on the [old docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.split.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.split) it looks like you can do the same thing by specifying the `return_type='frame'` parameter.