# Grouping and ungrouping based on a column

Tags: python, r, csv, pandas

My goal is to be able to group rows of a CSV file by a column value, and also to perform the inverse operation. To give an example, it is desired to be able to transform back and forth between these two formats:

```
uniqueId, groupId, feature_1, feature_2
1, 100, text of 1, 10
2, 100, some text of 2, 20
3, 200, text of 3, 30
4, 200, more text of 4, 40
5, 100, another text of 5, 50
```

Grouped on the groupId:

```
uniqueId, groupId, feature_1, feature_2
1|2|5, 100, text of 1|some text of 2|another text of 5, 10|20|50
3|4, 200, text of 3|more text of 4, 30|40
```

The delimiter (here |) is assumed to not exist anywhere in the data.

I am trying to use Pandas to perform this transformation. My code so far can access the cell of rows grouped by a groupId, but I do not know how to populate the new dataframe.

How can my method be completed to accomplish the transformation into the desired new df?

How would an inverse method look like, that transforms the new df back to the original one?

If R is a better tool for this job, I am also open to suggestions in R.

```
import pandas as pd  

def getGroupedDataFrame(df, groupByField, delimiter):
''' Create a df with the rows grouped on groupByField, values separated by delimiter'''
    groupIds = set(df[groupByField])
    df_copy = pd.DataFrame(index=groupIds,columns=df.columns)
    # iterate over the different groupIds
    for groupId in groupIds:
        groupRows = df.loc[df[groupByField] == groupId]
        # for all rows of the groupId
        for index, row in groupRows.iterrows():
            # for all columns in the df
            for column in df.columns:
                print row[column]
                # this prints the value the cell
                # here append row[column] to its cell in the df_copy row of groupId, separated by delimiter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform the grouping, you can `groupby` on `'groupId'`, and then within each group perform a join with your given delimiter on each column:

```
def group_delim(grp, delim='|'):
    """Join each columns within a group by the given delimiter."""
    return grp.apply(lambda col: delim.join(col))

# Make sure the DataFrame consists of strings, then apply grouping function.
grouped = df.astype(str).groupby('groupId').apply(group_delim)

# Drop the grouped groupId column, and replace it with the index groupId.
grouped = grouped.drop('groupId', axis=1).reset_index()
```

The grouped output:

```
  groupId uniqueId                                   feature_1 feature_2
0     100    1|2|5  text of 1|some text of 2|another text of 5  10|20|50
1     200      3|4                    text of 3|more text of 4     30|40
```

Similar idea for the inverse process, but since each row is a unique group you can just use a regular `apply`, no need for a `groupby`:

```
def ungroup_delim(col, delim='|'):
    """Split elements in a column by the given delimiter, stacking columnwise"""
    return col.str.split(delim, expand=True).stack()

# Apply the ungrouping function, and forward fill elements that aren't grouped.
ungrouped = grouped.apply(ungroup_delim).ffill()

# Drop the unwieldy altered index for a new one.
ungrouped = ungrouped.reset_index(drop=True)
```

And ungrouping yields the original data:

```
  groupId uniqueId          feature_1 feature_2
0     100        1          text of 1        10
1     100        2     some text of 2        20
2     100        5  another text of 5        50
3     200        3          text of 3        30
4     200        4     more text of 4        40
```

To use different delimiters, you'd just pass `delim` as an argument to `apply`:

```
foo.apply(group_delim, delim=';')
```

As a side note, in general iterating over DataFrames is quite slow.  Whenever possible you'll want to use a vectorized approach like what I've done above.

Comment: I noticed that in an older version of Pandas for col.str.split(delim, expand=True), expand is not a known keyword argument. A solution to circumvent this is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35567326/3229995

Answer (score 2):

A solution in R:

I define the initial data frame (for clarity)

```
df <- data.frame(uniqueID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
           groupID = c(100,100,200,200,100),
           feature_1 = c("text of 1","some text of 2",
                       "text of 3", "more text of 4",
                       "another text of 5"),
           feature_2 = c(10,20,30,40,50), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

To obtain the grouped data frame:

```
# Group and summarise using dplyr
library(dplyr)
grouped <- df %>% group_by(groupID) %>% summarise_each(funs(paste(.,collapse = "|")))
```

Output:

```
grouped

 groupID uniqueID                                  feature_1 feature_2
    (dbl)    (chr)                                      (chr)     (chr)
1     100    1|2|5 text of 1|some text of 2|another text of 5  10|20|50
2     200      3|4                   text of 3|more text of 4     30|40
```

To ungroup and go back to the original data frame:

```
library(stringr)
apply(grouped, 1, function(x)  {

        temp <- data.frame(str_split(x, '\\|'), stringsAsFactors = F)
        colnames(temp) <- names(x)
        temp

        }) %>%
        bind_rows()
```

Output:

```
  groupID uniqueID         feature_1 feature_2
    (chr)    (chr)             (chr)     (chr)
1     100        1         text of 1        10
2     100        2    some text of 2        20
3     100        5 another text of 5        50
4     200        3         text of 3        30
5     200        4    more text of 4        40
```